# Как получить частоту музыки на html 5 audio api

Tags: javascript, html5, web-audio

Есть мелодия, есть `HTML5` `audio api`, цель - получить частоту, с учетом времени. Чтобы в дальнейшем сравнить их. Все в основном сделал, выход подключил, с `audioCоntext` соединился, громкость, время, события - все получается. Но частота...

Comment: частота дискретизации в разных форматах компрессии может меняться. Напр. mp3 файл состоит из независимых «фреймов» (кадров), внутри каждого может быть своя частота: один на 44100Hz, следующий всего на 11025Hz.

Comment: Вот мне бы это и получить хотелось бы:)

Comment: Попробуйте [AudioContext.sampleRate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/sampleRate), но есть подозрение, что он отдаёт не детали проигрываемого файла, а частоту «на выходе» декодера, и там всегда будет 44.1k или 48 или 96 – в зависимости от аудиоинтерфейса.